# How to do ssh to an ec2 server using Jenkins pipeline with pem file

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to do ssh to an ec2 instance through Jenkins pipeline,using a pem file present on my local system, but I am unable to connect to ec2 instance.

ssh command

```
ssh -i test.pem -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@ip -p22
```

I am to able to connect to aws instance through my local machine. I am running jenkins pipeline on master node only. is there any issue with the user of pem file as the username is ubuntu for the pem file not as jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue by installing the ssh agent plugin in jenkins. After installing ssh agent plugin we need to configure server details under Manage Jenkins -> Manage Credential. Here we need to give the host name, user and passkey which would be your pem file.

While adding the ssh agent into your jenkins pipeline script, one can follow the below approach.

```
sshagent(credentials : ['id_name_added_underManageCredential']){

   sh "ssh command"

}
```